# How to disable bluetooth collaboration

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device and I've discovered that my wireless card has a configuration called "Bluetooth collaboration" which slows down the WiFi connection. I have also discovered that if I disable that option the connection speed will be restored.

My only problem is that the option I want doesn't appear on the wireless card configuration.

If someone knows how I can disable that configuration using drivers or using the command line, please help me.

I have already tried to reinstall Windows, to update my BIOS and my drivers. My PC model is Asus x556U.

[image: My network cards and bluetooth]

Comment: What you’re looking for is an Intel option. You won’t find it in drivers for Atheros hardware.

Comment: @DanielB what kind of intel option?

Comment: @JoãoGorgulho The kind of option that you find *only* in Intel chips drivers and software.

Comment: @DanielB ah ok, thanks, I will keep searching some options to resolve that problem if you have any idea to resolve that problem I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to disable collaboration and prefer interference - effectively having your wifi and bluetooth shout over each other?

Your speed will be exactly the same but with collaboration both will have a stable signal as they generously share the same frequency band.

Answer (score -2):

In general, two places can be checked:

1. Device Manager > Network adapter and right click the Bluetooth driver > Advanced. Under properties look for “Bluetooth Collaboration” and set the value to disabled.
2. Device Manager > Network Adapters > Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter (right click and choose "Properties". Under the 
   "Advanced" tab, highlight the setting named "Bluetooth Collaboration", then change it to disable.

Sorry, I don’t know  a command or a powershell script can disable this setting.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that option doesn´t show anywhere, that's why I asked for a power shell command, but I will keep searching for that. But if you discover something pls leave a comment!

Comment: @Origami Again: https://superuser.com/questions/1306546/how-to-disable-bluetooth-collaboration#comment1941024_1306546